# Prove that $f(x)=x$ is the only function satisfying certain properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of positive integers. Prove that $f(x)=x$ is the only function from $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ for which $(x^2 + f(y)) | (f(x)^2 + y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}.$

It's straightforward to show that $f(x)=x$ satisfies the required properties. Let $f$ be a function satisfying the problem conditions. Then $1+f(1) | (f(1)^2 + 1).$ Letting $a = f(1)$, we get a contradiction for $a > 1$ as $a^2 + 1\equiv 2\mod a+1\not\equiv 0\mod a+1$. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ We know that $(1^2 + f(k)) | (f(1)^2 + k) = (k+1).$ So clearly $f(k) \leq k.$  $(k^2 + f(1)) | (f(k)^2 + 1).$ Thus if $f(k) < k,$ we get a contradiction. So $f(k) = k.$

> Am I missing something above or is my proof correct?

Comment: You didn’t rule out the case $f(1) = 0$. This is a pretty trivial one - we would have $0 \mid f(0)^2 + 1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @MarkSaving . On this site, most users use $\Bbb N$ for the positive integers. If this is what the proposer means, then the proof is correct.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Oh dear. I don’t want the comments to devolve into a flame war over whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, but I think it’s pretty safe to say that mathematicians generally consider $0$ to be a natural number, including most on this site. There are lots of good reasons for this.

Comment: @MarkSaving . I prefer $0\in\Bbb N$ too, as we have $\Bbb Z^+$ for the positive integers. But on this site I reluctantly conform to $\Bbb N=\Bbb Z^+$ because almost everyone else here does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks fine. Just for fun, here is another way to prove things.

Since $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $x+f(x)$ is positive for all $x\ge1$, so

$$(x^2+f(y))\mid(f(x)^2+y)\implies x^2+f(y)\le f(x)^2+y\implies f(y)-y\le(f(x)-x)(f(x)+x)$$

Setting $x=y$, we find that $f(y)-y\le(f(y)-y)(f(y)+y)$, which tells us $f(y)-y\ge0$ (since $f(y)+y\gt0$ for $y\ge1$).  It thus suffices to show that $f(1)=1$, since that will give us $f(y)=y$ for all $y$ from $0\le f(y)-y\le(f(1)-1)(f(1)+1)=0$.

To show $f(1)=1$, note that $(1^2+f(1))\mid(f(1)^2+1$ implies $f(1)^2+1=k(1+f(1))$ for some positive integer $k$, from which the quadratic formula tells us

$$f(1)={-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4(1-k)}\over2}$$

But for this to be an integer, we must have $k^2-4(1-k)=(k+2)^2-8=m^2$ for some integer $m$.  And the only two squares that differ by $8$ are $9$ and $1$, which tells us $k=1$, and thus $f(1)^2+1=1+f(1)$, which simplifies first to $f(1)^2=f(1)$ and then to $f(1)=1$ (since $f(1)\ge1$).